# Using Express Migration Tool to migrate WFFM data

Tags: wffm, express-migration-tool

I dont seems to be able to find any documentation on this:

I am upgrading from 7.2 to 8.2 using the Express Migration Tool. I am including WFFM in the upgrade. To upgrade WFFM analytics data I need to make 82 use SQL for storing data, as opposed to Mongo.

What are the implications of this?

Mostly worried about the following:

- Can I switch back to Mongo after the Upgrade?
- Will I lose my data then?
- Will I need to rebuild the reporting database?

[Walkthrough: Rebuilding the reporting database](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database)

Answer (score 1):

The [Express Migration Tool 2.0](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool/20/Express_Migration_Tool_20_Initial_Release.aspx) migrates Web Forms For Marketers 2.4 items and data.